# Get Array of All Existing Page Routes in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I'm making a `404` page in Gatsby and I want to give the user a suggestion for a similar path name based on the path they have gone to (which doesn't exist). How do I get an array of all the existing pages in my website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gatsby exposes information about every page you tell it about (either via the `pages` folder or the `createPage` API) as a GraphQL field called `allSitePage`. I tend to create a hook like this on most of my projects so it's easy to get at this information:

```js
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"

const useInternalPaths = () => {
  const {
    pages: { nodes },
  } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      pages: allSitePage {
        nodes {
          path
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return nodes.map(node => node.path)
}
```